# Scrollable Activity, non-scrollable ListView - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, scrollable

I need a way to make the Activity scrollable, but the ListViews unscrollable. I've tried different ways that I've found, but none of them have worked so far.

Comment: Can you give more details of why you'd want this?

Comment: If you want a non-scrolling `View`, then there's really no point in using a `ListView`. Use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NestedScrollView`? It works well with `RecyclerView`, but I'm not sure about `ListView`.

Try something like this.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Your header above your list. -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Header" />

        <!-- The list and it's contents. -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The footer below your list. -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Footer" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be better if you give more details.
We use `ListView` when we have a list of items with different values. For scenarios that our views may overflow the screen and may not be visible, `ScrollView` or in some situations `NestedScrollView` are the answer to solve the problem. And remember to put all contents in a Layout tag like `LinearLayout` and put it inside the `ScrollView`.